# Traversing elements in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to change the href of link in a box. I can only use native javaScript. Somehow I have problems traversing through the elements in order to match the correct `<a>` tag.

Since all the a tags inside this container are identical except for their href value, I need to use this value to get a match.

So far I have tried with this:

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('ic-Login-confirmation__content');
var terms = box.querySelectorAll('a');
if (typeof(box) != 'undefined' && box != null) {
  for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
    if (terms[i].href.toLowerCase() == 'http://www.myweb.net/2/') {
      terms[i].setAttribute('href', 'http://newlink.com');
    }
  }
}
```

However, I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: box.querySelectorAll is not a function". What do I need to do in order to make this work?

[Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4y6k8g4g/1/).

Comment: Can you not just do `document.querySelectorAll('[href="http://www.myweb.net/2/"]')`?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` (note the **s**) returns a list of DOM elements, not a single one. You cannot apply `querySelectorAll()` to a list of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beauty of `querySelectorAll` is you dont need to traverse like that - just use

```
var terms = document.querySelectorAll('.ic-Login-confirmation__content a');
```

And then iterate those. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4y6k8g4g/2/

In fact, this whole thing can be much simpler

```
var terms = document.querySelectorAll('.ic-Login-confirmation__content a[href="http://www.myweb.net/2/"]');
if(terms.length){
    terms[0].setAttribute('href', 'http://newlink.com');
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/4y6k8g4g/4/

Comment: I like the beauty and simplicity of this solution. However, what if I have two or more links with the same href? The terms[0] will only work for the first one?

Comment: @Meek - indeed, in which case iterate over all those returned from `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's just perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('ic-Login-confirmation__content')[0];
```

Since you are using `getElementsByClassName` ,it will return an array of elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can select by `href` attr with querySelector,
try this:

```
document.querySelector('a[href="http://www.myweb.net/2/"]')
```

---

instead of defining the exact `href` attribute you can simplify it even more :

```
document.querySelector('a[href?="myweb.net/2/"]'
```

matches only elments with href attribute that end with `"myweb.net/2/"`

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByClassName` method returns returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.

You need to specify it as follows for this instance:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ic-Login-confirmation__content')[0]
```

This will ensure that you are accessing the correct node in your HTML. If you `console.log` the `box` variable in your example you will see an array returned.

Comment: And this will fail with a undefined error later if no matching element is found.

Comment: It will not be an error...the variable will just return 'undefined'. So this will not block your JS code from executing.

Comment: As I mentioned: Later. The code will be something like 'var a = document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0]', a will be undefined, and later in the code someone will try to access a property of 'a' and the script will stop.